# Правильно ли обособлено "точнее"

Tags: пунктуация

> Небольшой городок, точнее, поселок утопал в зелени

Почему пунктуация в этом предложении верна? Ведь здесь мы не можем удалить обособленную уточняющую конструкцию. Мне кажется, должно быть так:

> Небольшой городок, точнее поселок, утопал в зелени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему пунктуация в этом предложении верна?

См. **Остроумова О., Фрамполь О.  "Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений":**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

При словах "вернее", "точнее", "скорее" возможны варианты пунктуации.

> Обратимся к справочникам.
>
> [В Справочнике по русскому языку Д. Э. Розенталя, в параграфе 22 (Уточняющие члены предложения)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118), сказано: Уточняющий характер придают высказыванию слова ***вернее, точнее, иначе, скорее и т. п.*** Однако следующие за ними члены предложения не обособляются, так как указанные слова, имеющие значение вводных ***(точнее, вернее, иначе по смыслу равнозначны словосочетаниям точнее говоря, вернее говоря, иначе говоря),*** сами выделяются запятыми: **Его доброта, вернее, его великодушие тронуло меня.**
>
> [Полный академический справочник](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123)говорит следующее: Запятая ставится только перед этими словами, которые НЕ ОТДЕЛЯЮТСЯ от уточняющего члена предложения.
> Напр.: Он переутомился, а вернее болен.
>
> [В справочнике по пунктуации на Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach2/), сказано следующее:
>
> "В примерах из художественной литературы часто встречается иная расстановка знаков препинания: уточняющие члены предложения, вводимые словами ***вернее, точнее,*** обособляются, а сами эти слова, стоящие в начале обособленного оборота, в соответствии с общим правилом не отделяются от него запятой (но иногда могут быть отделены тире):
>
> ***К сожалению, врачи еще мало умеют распознавать истерическую, вернее психическую, природу ряда заболеваний. И. Ефремов, Лезвие бритвы. Анализировать прошлое, вернее – дурное в прошлом, имеет смысл только в том случае, когда на основании этого анализа можно исправить настоящее или подготовить будущее. В. Некрасов, В окопах Сталинграда. Хочется писать легкое, а не трудное. Трудное – это когда пишешь, думая о том, что кто-то прочтет. Ветка синтаксиса, вернее – розга синтаксиса, всё время грозит тебе. Ю. Олеша, Книга прощания.***